# Which HTTP status to return on domain data error?

Tags: web-services, rest, http, status

I'm developing a RESTful application that integrates with other webservices.

My question is, which HTTP status should I return if my client posts data that is invalid for one of those webservices? For example, if it posts a name that is invalid for a webservice that my application uses, which of the 4** status codes should I return, considering it's a user input error?

Some considerations I've made, and why I'm not comfortable of using them:

- 400: The data is invalid, but not the request format itself
- 403: The server is not refusing to respond, although the data is invalid
- 406: The error is in a provided parameter, not in the "accept" header
- 412: The error has nothing to do with "If-Match" header

So, what would you use in this case?

Comment: Something that might help to understand this scenario: suppose the webservice my application uses says that the user is deactivated, so that webservice cannot operate on him.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In real life, HTTP status codes for REST and other web services can be vague and hard to clearly specify.  Things also get interesting if your client is actually talking to a proxy server and that proxy sends back its own status.  If there's a problem in your web service (perhaps below your app) you may just get 500.

In the past I would opt for returning 200 and using your own JSON-or-whatever structure for returning error information for your client.

Comment: Nice, thanks, I'll use status 200 and "successful" as one of the JSON response properties. :-)

Comment: Another thing you might consider is sending down a special http response header.  X-MyServer-Magic.  If your client doesn't see that header then it's likely talking to a captive web portal or something.  Some may call this over-engineering but it's from real-life issues I've had to deal with.

Comment: Agreed with Julian. Do not return 200.

Comment: I agree that the REST 'spec' stipulates HTTP status codes for indicating success/failure.  However real life experience isn't always quite this simple.  If you get a 200, how do you know your call wasn't intercepted by a captive portal?  How do you interpret 500's?  So what I've done is assume 2xx means "it works as far as talking to my service" but use error handing where I can fully control the semantics.

Comment: I agree to seand; HTTP statuses are a really nice source of information about the success of the communication between a client and a service, but they just don't always go as far as we need. So what I did was to embed a "successful" field in my JSON response, and, if not, the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Stick with 400, or have a look at 422 (which may be close to what you need).

Comment: 422 seems to be WebDAV-specific, I wonder how that could affect the semantics of my service. 400 is a malformed request, not what I want. But thanks for the tips anyway. :-)

Comment: No, 422 is not WebDAV specific. It just happens to be defined in WebDAV.